# Android: How to show back button for top-level activity that is also not a top-level activity?

Tags: android

So, my AppBarConfiguration looks like this with top-level activities. My "home" and "contact" work fine. However, my category takes a parameter and I can drill into sub-categories, so only the first one is a top-level. So, of course, the back button will never show on those screens with this configuration. How can I "show" and "hide" the back button programatically for those?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_category, R.id.nav_contact)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_home:
                    navController.navigate(R.id.nav_home, bundle);
                    return true;
                ......
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATE: Here is the function I created in MainActivity. It correctly shows/hides the back button, but it messes up the drawer functionality.

```
public void updateToolbar(boolean upEnabled) {
    if (upEnabled) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    } else {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a second destination specifically for the sub-categories that uses the same Fragment class. This would mean that you *would* be at a separate destination id and `AppBarConfiguation` could tell the two cases apart.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the back button in the actionBar. I run into similar problem when combining DrawerLayout and Navigation, and each of the items in the DrawerLayout led to separate sub nav-graphs. Maybe it is applicable to your problem.

Note, the code samples provided are written in Kotlin, but it should be quite readable and you should be able to convert it to java code. 
In the activity where you initialize your AppBarConfiguration, add a flag `canNavigateUp: Boolean` and call `updateToolbar(true)` when you drill into sub-categories, it should update the back/home button accordingly.

```
private var canNavigateUp: Boolean = false
private val navigationController: NavController = findNavController(...)
private val appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration = ...

fun updateToolbar(navigateUpEnabled: Boolean) {
    supportActionBar?.let { actionBar ->
        canNavigateUp = navigateUpEnabled
        if (navigateUpEnabled) {
            // use null to set android default back icon, or pass a drawable to set custom icon
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(null)
        } else {
            // set android default home icon
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
        }
    }
}
```

The above means you need a way for the sub-categories Fragments/Activities to access the Activity which implements the `updateToolbar(boolean)` function. In my case I had 1 host activity that sets up the navigation, the rest are Fragments that are on top of that activity, so accessing it was easy: `fragment.getActivity()?.updateToolbar(boolean)`. Your implementation may vary in this regard.

In my case, I also had to override `onSupportNavigateUp()` to correctly handle navigation of the sub-graphs.

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return if (canNavigateUp) {
        navigationController.navigateUp()
    } else {
        NavigationUI.navigateUp(navigationController, appBarConfiguration)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i tried your advice and it shows the back button icons correctly, but it messes up my drawer icon. On the first screen it hides the drawer icon, and on other screens it shows the back button, but when you click it, it opens the drawer.

Comment: Can you update your question with the detail code of the activity where you set the AppBarConfiguration?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `onSupportNavigateUp()` in that Activity as my answer describes? I dont see it in your code sample. I also had the buttons messed up when I didnt override that function.

Comment: Yes, I tried overriding and was still having problems. I'm sure this solution works but I probably had something set incorrectly. I ended up using the solution below. Thanks!